# SQL: Return a Y if a value exists

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm VERY new to SQL, so I apologize if this is an easy one or if my code is not proper.
I have a data set(let's call it employee numbers) that I already have a query for. It has over 2400 results. I'n on Oracle 10g

I have 2 problems:

1. The query has a cartesian product issue. I only need the most recent record from the fields in the select statement
2. I need to find how many of them have a row in table JOB that has a value of REH(rehire) in field SYSADM.PS_JOB.ACTION_REASON. I don't need to return the REH record info, just a simple Y or N for each record from the below query.

I have no idea how to do this.

Here's my query so far.

```
SELECT a.paygroup, a.EMPLID, a.FILE_NBR, c.name, e.TLM_STATUS, b.rehire_dt    
as "Emplmnt_Rltd_Dtes-Rehire Date"
FROM PS_EMPLOYMENT b

inner join SYSADM.PS_JOB a
 on a.emplid = b.emplid

inner join SYSADM.PS_PERSONAL_DATA c
  on a.emplid = c.emplid

inner join SYSADM.PS_SMS_SUBSCRB_TBL d
 on a.paygroup = d.SUBSCRIBER_ID

Inner join PORTAL.PS_TS_EMPL_TLM_STATUS e
  on a.emplid = e.emplid

where

b.rehire_dt IS NOT NULL
and d.EFFDT = (select max (d2.effdt) from PS_SMS_SUBSCRB_TBL d2 where      
    d.SUBSCRIBER_ID = d2.SUBSCRIBER_ID)
and e.EFFDT = (select max (e2.effdt) from PORTAL.PS_TS_EMPL_TLM_STATUS e2    
   where e.emplid = e2.EMPLID)
and d.EFF_STATUS <> 'T'

order by a.paygroup, a.emplid
```

Thanks for your help!

Kind Regards,
Craig

Comment: What a mess... right outer join... executing as inner join...

Comment: Funny enough I had it as a right outer join originally, but that didnt' change the results.

Comment: Are the joined fields are unique columns

Comment: The unique ID across all tables(except 1) is EMPLID. SYSADM.PS_SMS_SUBSCRB_TBL unique is subscriber_id

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. just changed the select statement to this

```
Select a.paygroup, a.EMPLID, a.FILE_NBR, c.name, e.TLM_STATUS, b.rehire_dt as  
"Emplmnt_Rltd_Dtes-Rehire Date", 
  CASE 
    WHEN a.ACTION_REASON = 'REH' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM PS_EMPLOYMENT b --no effective dated rows
```